# asp.net login system via c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have four pages `login.aspx` , `main.aspx`, `Sub.aspx`, `final.aspx`. Final page needs authentication to be accessed  which i have provided using forms authentication.Logging in through `login.aspx` it redirects to `final.aspx` because `defaultUrl` is set to `final.aspx` .currently i am going from `main.aspx` to `sub.aspx` to `final.aspx` which redirects to `login.aspx` after logging in `final.aspx`. what i want is if i start from `login.aspx` it should redirect to `main.aspx` to `sub.aspx` to `final.aspx`, jumping from `sub.aspx` to `final.aspx` should not redirects to login as already logged in.
But directly accessing the `final.aspx` should always redirects to `login.aspx`

login code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBox1 .Text =="abc" && TextBox2 .Text =="xyz")
    {
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(TextBox1.Text, false);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("w");
    }
}
```

final page code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (User .Identity .IsAuthenticated )
    {
        Response.Write("welcome");
    }
    else
    {
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
    }
}
```

web config

```
<authentication mode ="Forms">
    <forms name ="abc" loginUrl ="login.aspx" defaultUrl="final.aspx"/>
  </authentication>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like that:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
       Response.Write("welcome");
    }
    else
    {
       Response.Redirect("/login.aspx");
    }
 }
```

I probably would first show a message "Not authorised. Please log in" with a link to the login page. instead of redirecting.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i think you misunderstood the question

Comment: Could be. I am not sure what you mean with redirect to and to ... Don't you have logic on each page to decide what to do with a request?

Comment: case 1 - if i start the application with login page first the result will be redirecting to final.aspx ,but i need it to go to main page  to sub to final(which out asking for login)                                                                                                                   case 2 - if i start the application with main page and then to  sub page. user should be redirected to login.aspx and after successful login it should redirect to final.aspx      - in both cases accessing the final page directly should always redirect to login and i am using hyperlinks in pages to move

Comment: Do you have webforms or mvc?

Comment: i am using webforms

Comment: I would remove defaultUrl="final.aspx" from the web.config and see what difference it makes. I think you don't need it. I don't have this in my web.configs.

Answer (score 0):

I popose you a better use Session for this case to handle the URL redirecting and authentication.

Try this

**To use Session, you need to inherit "Page" in your class :**

```
public class Class1 : Page
```

**Sub page**

**aspx:**

```
<a id="gotofinal" href="#" OnClick="GoToFinal_Click">Go To Final</a>
```

**aspx.cs:**

```
protected void GoToFinal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Session["GoToFinal"] = "Y";
   Response.Redirect("final.aspx");
}
```

**Final Page :**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     if ((string)Session[IsAuthenticated] == "Y")
     {
         Session["GoToFinal"] = "";
         Response.Write("welcome");
     }
     else
     {
         Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
     } 
}
```

**Login page :**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Session["IsAuthenticated"] = "";
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TextBox1.Text == "abc" && TextBox2.Text == "xyz")
        {
            Session["IsAuthenticated"] = "Y";

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["GoToFinal"]) && (string)Session["GoToFinal"] == "Y")
            {
                Response.Redirect("final.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("main.aspx");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Login Failed");
        }
    }
```

You also need to make logout button in final.aspx to clear the Session[IsAuthenticated]

```
Session["IsAuthenticated"] = "";
```

Hope it helps.